# Docker intermittently failing to start container

Tags: linux, containers, docker, lxc

I'm using Docker with Jenkins to run Rspec tests, and I'm getting this intermittent error:

`[workspace] $ /bin/bash /tmp/hudson4240670520825002309.sh
2014/06/26 09:59:20 Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 9bc43e4695ddb8eaf87487d77cbec6175047936a01c8288a6aea1db35f760152: lstat /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-docker-202:16-722147-d8487a48f2b3ce220752c594cc499130a29807656c61eb210d24a6a7ce12832d-init: no such file or directory
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure`

It only takes about 30 seconds for this error to occur, so it's barely started the test suite. When it works, the output looks like this:

`[workspace] $ /bin/bash /tmp/hudson2461424205491831045.sh
Starting supervisor: supervisord.
app.rb start
Bundler start`

The script that Jenkins runs is very simple: 

`docker run --rm=true -t --privileged=true -v ${WORKSPACE}:/www/app myapp "bundle exec rspec spec/`

Any ideas why this might fail once in a while?

Comment: You could start the Docker daemon in debug mode to get a better clue. See `--debug=true` https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#daemon

Comment: did you run -d (detach) mode? you can try to run the container outside of jenkins and configured as slave node to see whether it is ok. Also put the configuration in the job besides console output.

Comment: It's also possible to tail `/var/log/docker.log` for more detail.

Comment: Depending on your system, the log might be somewhere else. On Ubuntu 14.10, it's in /var/log/upstart/docker.log